# anacondaでpandasを使うモジュールをpyinstallerでexe化出来ない

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

pandasを使ったモジュールをexe化しようとしても上手く行かずに困っています。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgres.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "c:\users\Username\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 68, in <module>
  File "site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources\extern\__init__.py", line 61, in load_module
  ImportError: The 'appdirs' package is required; normally this is bundled with this package so if you get this warning, consult the packager of your distribution.
Failed to execute script pyi_rth_pkgres
```

環境は
・Windows10
・Anaconda(64-bit)

これまで試したこと
・https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109324/pyinstaller-and-pandas　を参考にspecファイルをいじるも失敗
・pyinstallerをpipではなくcondaで入れて

```
conda install -c acellera pyinstaller=3.2.3
```

を使おうと思っても通常のとどう違うのかわからない

とにかく色々試してみましたが、どうも上手く行きません。
どうか助けてください

Answer (score 4, accepted):

自己解決したので、後続の方たちのために成功時の流れを書きます。
主に参考にしたのはこのサイトでした　
http://www.slideshare.net/dondokono/pyconjp-2016

```
conda create -n 環境名 pywin32 setuptools=19.2 pandas matplotlib
```

で仮想環境を構築し、

```
activate 環境名
```

で仮想環境を動かします。

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

でpyinstallerを仮想環境内にインストールして、作業ディレクトリに移動します。
ここでとりあえず

```
pyinstaller --onefile 変換ファイル名.py
```

と入れると、変換には成功しますが、実行すると

```
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_avx2.dll or mkl_def.dll
```

とでるので、specファイルに

```
     a = Analysis(['変換ファイル名.spec'],
         pathex=['C:\\Users\\Username\\作業ディレクトリ'],
         binaries=None,
         datas=[('C:\\Users\\Username\\Anaconda3\\envs\\環境名\\Library\\bin\\mkl_avx2.dll','.'),
                ('C:\\Users\\Username\\Anaconda3\\envs\\環境名\\Library\\bin\\mkl_def.dll','.')],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher)
```

を追加します。ただ、これだとpandasとかを認識してくれないので、
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109324/pyinstaller-and-pandas を参考に、最終的には

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None

def get_pandas_path():
    import pandas
    pandas_path = pandas.__path__[0]
    return pandas_path

def get_plt_path():
    import matplotlib
    plt_path = matplotlib.__path__[0]
    return plt_path

a = Analysis(['変換ファイル名.spec'],
     pathex=['C:\\Users\\Username\\作業ディレクトリ'],
     binaries=None,
     datas=[('C:\\Users\\Username\\Anaconda3\\envs\\環境名\\Library\\bin\\mkl_avx2.dll','.'),
            ('C:\\Users\\Username\\Anaconda3\\envs\\環境名\\Library\\bin\\mkl_def.dll','.')],
     hiddenimports=[],
     hookspath=[],
     runtime_hooks=[],
     excludes=[],
     win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
     win_private_assemblies=False,
     cipher=block_cipher)

dict_tree = Tree(get_pandas_path(), prefix='pandas', excludes=["*.pyc"])
a.datas += dict_tree
a.binaries = filter(lambda x: 'pandas' not in x[0], a.binaries)

dict_tree = Tree(get_plt_path(), prefix='matplotlib', excludes=["*.pyc"])
a.datas += dict_tree
a.binaries = filter(lambda x: 'matplotlib' not in x[0], a.binaries)


pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      name='変換ファイル名',
      debug=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      console=True )
```

とspecファイルを書き換え

```
pyinstaller 変換ファイル名.spec --onefile
```

を実行して無事解決しました。
ただ、現状exeファイルの起動と実行に時間がかかること
自分で書いたモジュールのインポートが出来ないのが問題なので、そのうち改善していきたいと思います