# Windows10上でPyInstallerを使用したexeの実行エラー

Tags: python, windows-10, python2, pyinstaller

Windows10でPyInstallerを使用してPythonスクリプトをexeにしました。
ところが、そのexeを実行しようとしたら、下記エラーを生じました。

```
C:\*********\dist\*********>********* --arg1 123
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "*********", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\ishihara\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-jxtpvz\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
  File "site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
ImportError: C extension: No module named np_datetime not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first.
[4832] Failed to execute script 288-FittingPG
```

どうやら、importしているpandasが無いというエラーのようです。
よろしくお願いします。

追加情報です。
ご推薦の方法で試したところ、画面のメッセージがでました。
ここではできないようです。
よろしくお願いします。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: http://ikapblg.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-91.html に**tcl関連のエラーが出るとき。**の対応が記載されていました。参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: @ishihara-flicfit さん、コード部分やエラーメッセージ部分は、Markdown のコードブロック記法を使って装飾して頂けると、行頭のスペースがそのまま表示されるなどするためありがたいです。編集時にエラーメッセージ部分をマウスカーソルで範囲選択し、エディタ上部の `{}` を押すと自動的に装飾できますので、どうぞお試しください。

Comment: 関連?: [anacondaでpandasを使うモジュールをpyinstallerでexe化出来ない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/30125/19110)

Comment: [この回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32974358/5989200)にあるように、`import pandas` して Hello World するだけのプログラムでも **同じ** エラーが出るか試すと、原因の切り分けができるかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージ、「ImportError: C extension: No module named np_datetime not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first.」
[直訳] 『インポートエラー： C extension: np_datetimeというモジュールが無い、ビルドされていない。ソースディレクトリからpandasをインポートするなら、C extensionをビルドするために、'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force'を真っ先に実行する必要がある。』
に従って、'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force'というコマンドを実行してから、exeにしたPythonスクリプトを実行してみてください。

拙訳が、「どうやら、importしているpandasが無いというエラーのようです」という御意見と、どう関係するのかは判りません。

質問に貼られているスクリーンショットのエラーメッセージの内容はnp_datetimeがtimedeltasになっているだけで、'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' を実行する必要があるとの助言は同じです。